# "Visited" vs "Seen" Positions in Breadth-First Search

Tags: algorithms, python, breadth-first-search, maze

I'm struggling to understand why there is such a radical difference in the execution time and number of steps required by two seemingly similar algorithms for Breadth-First Search in a 2d grid.

In the Python program below, uncommenting the indicated lines switches between versions.

As well as help with understanding the difference, I would like to know if there is a "canonical" version which is considered best practice. Clearly here the second version performs best, but it is a also different to most of the statements of the algorithm I have found, which add the current node to a "visited" list straight after dequeuing.

### BFS Algorithm

These versions store the whole path at each stage in the queue.

#### Version 1

Enqueue a list containing the start position, as the initial path.
while the queue has elements in it:
    dequeue the next path
    name the last element `frontier`
    **add the frontier to a set of visited positions**
    check if the frontier is the goal position
        if so, return the path
    otherwise, check neighbouring cells:
        if the cell is legal and is not in the set of visited positions,
             enqueue a new path consisting of the current path + this new cell
if no successful path was found, return None

#### Version 2

Enqueue a list containing the start position, as the initial path.
while the queue has elements in it:
    dequeue the next path
    name the last element `frontier`
    check if the frontier is the goal position
        if so, return the path
    otherwise, check neighbouring cells:
        if the cell is legal and is not in the set of previously seen cells,
             enqueue a new path consisting of the current path + this new cell
             **add the current cell to a set of previously seen cells.**
if no successful path was found, return None

````
import collections


offsets = {
    "up": (-1, 0),
    "right": (0, 1),
    "down": (1, 0),
    "left": (0, -1)
}

def is_legal_position(maze, pos):
    i, j = pos
    num_rows = len(maze)
    num_cols = len(maze[0])
    return 0 <= i < num_rows and 0 <= j < num_cols


def bfs(grid, start, end):
    """
    Bread-First Search in a 2d list. Stores whole paths in queue.
    """
    queue = collections.deque([[start]])
    seen_or_visited = set()

    while queue:
        print("####### While queue is not empty #########")
        path = queue.popleft()
        print("Path", path)
        frontier = path[-1]
        print("Frontier:", frontier)
        seen_or_visited.add(frontier) # Uncomment for version (1)
        if frontier == end:
            return path
        enqueued_this_round = []
        for direction in ["up", "right", "down", "left"]:
            print("### Direction: ", direction)
            row_offset, col_offset = offsets[direction]
            next_pos = (frontier[0] + row_offset, frontier[1] + col_offset)
            if is_legal_position(grid, next_pos) and next_pos not in seen_or_visited:
                print("Enqueueing", next_pos)
                queue.append(path + [next_pos])
                # seen_or_visited.add(next_pos) # Uncomment for version (2)
                enqueued_this_round.append(next_pos)
        print("seen_or_visited:", seen_or_visited, "\n")
        print("Enqueued this round", enqueued_this_round, "\n")


maze = [[0] * 5 for row in range(5)]
start_pos = (4, 4)
end_pos = (0, 0)
print(bfs(maze, start_pos, end_pos))
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to take the same approach as I did to draw my conclusions: take a graphical approach to see the differences and drawbacks.

For that, do the following:

1. Comment out all `print` lines except `print("Frontier:", frontier)`
2. Then do `python program.py > version1.txt`, modify your program such that it represents verison 2, and then do `python program.py > version2.txt`.
3. Get pen & paper and draw a 4 × 4 table.

Here is a comparison of the first lines of both log files:

```
    Version 1           Version 2

Frontier: (4, 4)     Frontier: (4, 4)
Frontier: (3, 4)     Frontier: (3, 4)
Frontier: (4, 3)     Frontier: (3, 4)
Frontier: (2, 4)     Frontier: (4, 3)
Frontier: (3, 3)     Frontier: (2, 4)
Frontier: (3, 3)     Frontier: (4, 4)
Frontier: (4, 2)     Frontier: (3, 3)
```

I leave it as an exercise for you to draw this with pen & paper. Can you take it from here?

Note that the duplicate `(3, 4)` is version 2 is suspicious. Can you guess where it comes from?

> I would like to know if there is a "canonical" version which is considered best practice.

You typically want the invariant that everything in the queue is already put in the seen queue. As a formula, this amounts to saying $$\text{work queue}\ \subseteq\ \text{seen queue}.$$

Otherwise, you could pick the tip of the work queue, say item $i_1$, go through its neighbors to then add its neighbor $i_2$ to the work queue. However, $i_2$ was already part of the work queue before (perhaps just after $i_1$!), but you couldn't know since you didn't keep the seen queue synchronized.

Hence, implementing this invariant amounts in your code to

- putting start onto the seen queue

  ```
  queue = collections.deque([[start]])
  seen_or_visited = set([start])
  ```
- choosing version 2, i.e.

  ```
  seen_or_visited.add(next_pos) # Uncomment for version (2)
  ```

You may also want to comment out version 1, i.e.

```
#seen_or_visited.add(frontier) # Uncomment for version (1)
```

since the invariant, fulfilled by the two points above, guarantees that whatever you pick from the queue (here, `frontier`) has already been added to the seen queue.

By the way, your function is missing a `return None` in case it doesn't find the target position.